# Is $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

$R$ is the radius of convergence for a powerseries

I will write down my proof but I am not sure whether this is right because I thought  $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$ If I would take a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for which $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < 1 <\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$ wouldn't there be a **contradiction** for the respective power series. Because $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$ and the statement in my question would imply $\frac{1}{R}<\frac{1}{R}$

---

Please tell me where I made the mistake in my reasoning of the following proof:

#### i) $\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=:t\neq 0,\infty$

Applying the root criteria for an arbitrary power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_nz^n|}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n}||z|$$

Converges absolutely if

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n}||z|<1\iff |z|<\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n}|}=\frac{1}{t}\tag{*}$$

Diverges if

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n}||z|>1\iff |z|>\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n}|}=\frac{1}{t}\tag{**}$$

Suppose $\frac{1}{R}>t\iff R<\frac{1}{t}\Rightarrow R<\frac{R+\frac{1}{t}}{2}<\frac{1}{t}$

$(*) \Rightarrow \frac{R+\frac{1}{t}}{2}$, converges absolutely. **Contradiction**

Because $R:=\sup\{|z|:\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, converges$\}$

Suppose $\frac{1}{R}<t$, $(**) \Rightarrow$ The power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ diverges for $z=\frac{R+\frac{1}{t}}{2}$ **Contradiction**

Because $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<R, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n $ converges absolutely.

---

#### ii) $\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=:t\neq 0,\infty$

Applying the quotient criteria for an arbitrary power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{a_nz^n}|\iff \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}||z| $$

Converges absolutely if

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}||z|<1\iff|z|<\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|}= \frac{1}{t}\tag{***}$$

Diverges if

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}||z|>1\iff|z|>\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|}= \frac{1}{t}\tag{****}$$

Suppose $\frac{1}{R}>t\iff R<\frac{1}{t}\Rightarrow R<\frac{R+\frac{1}{t}}{2}<\frac{1}{t}$

$(***) \Rightarrow \frac{R+\frac{1}{t}}{2}$, converges absolutely. **Contradiction**

Because $R:=\sup\{|z|:\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, converges$\}$

Suppose $\frac{1}{R}<t$, $(****) \Rightarrow$ The powerseries $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ diverges for $z=\frac{R+\frac{1}{t}}{2}$ **Contradiction**

Because $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<R, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n $ converges absolutely.

---

#### i) + ii) $\Rightarrow  \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$

I am thinking about this for some time now please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: You probably want to remove the $n$'th power of $a_n$ in each one of its twelve occurrences.

Comment: This should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Finding_the_radius_of_convergence

Comment: Yes I will remove them

Comment: What's the radius of convergence of $1+2x+x^2+2x^3+x^4+2x^5+\cdots$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test and look for *inconclusive*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reading of the quotient criterion is partly wrong. The rule for divergence is that if
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}z^{n+1}|}{|a_nz^n|}=|z|\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}>1
$$
then the power series diverges. This gives you a third radius to consider. Thus you get
$$
R_{quot, sup}\le R_{root, sup}\le R_{quot,inf}
$$
and only the radius $R_{root, sup}$ of the root criterion gives the exact region of convergence of the power series. If the coefficient quotients to not have a strict limit, the quotient criterion leaves out an annulus where no claim towards convergence or divergence is possible.